# How to get desired routes for forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I will start by example.

Example:
There is a form with /profile/edit, and it gets /users after clicking submit in web browser.

What I want, is to make that, when someone clicks submit for form, it gets exactly the same URL, as it was (/profile/edit for the example).

How that can be done nicely?

P.S. By the way. Is it possible to use localization for Rails' routes (by example again: from this -> /profile/edit, to -> /profil/modifier)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your update action, use `redirect_to :back` or `redirect_to :action => :edit`
2. There are gems for i18nizing routes: [i18n_routing](https://github.com/kwi/i18n_routing) and [translate_routes](https://github.com/raul/translate_routes). I haven't used them, but I think they'll let you get started.